# Inserting div after destroyed session in login page

Tags: php, html

How could I insert a div with message of successful password change, when after successful change i redirect to login page like this?

```
header("Location: login.php");
```

Comment: title and question both are not understandable.

Comment: You can't (well you can but it wont be displayed for long), you'll need to pass some argument to login.php so it displays it for you, or to redirect using javascript inside the logout page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a query parameter in that redirect, and verify, in the redirected page, if that value is set. If is the case, make visible the `div` you want, which, previously, was set to be invisible, with css.

Like this:

```
header("Location: login.php?div=enabled");
```

Then, in the login.php page:

```
<style type="text/css">
.div{
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
 }
</style>
...

<?php
if (isset($_GET['div']) and $_GET['div'] == 'enabled'){
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
    .div{
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

So, if that query parameter is not set, or does'nt have "enabled" as value, the `div` will be hidden. But if the query param is set and have "enabled" as its value, then display the `div`.

Comment: This one's better..!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that by header then pass your message as a query string

```
header("Location: login.php?msg=password changed");
```

And the receive the message on login page print it

```
if(isset($_GET['msg'])){
    echo "<div class='class_name'>".$_GET['msg']."</div>"
}
```

Comment: It may not be a good idea to use `GET` method to do the job since I know it's easy..!

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai : yes I know. But as you see I already mentioned in my question `if you want to do it by header`.

Answer (score 0):

Use **GET** method and try something like this :

```
header("Location: login.php?str=successfull");
```

**And on login.php page :**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['str'])){ ?>
  <div><?php echo $_GET['str'];?></div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are doing so much changes while your all previous changes are valid and good. But not this one is as good

Comment: @urfusion, I need to add `<div>` in the answer, as it was user's requirement. But since there was problem in tags I re-edited it twice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little bit secure way to do it :

Use **`COOKIES`** if you don't want to do anything unsecure in `header` :

```
if ($query) {
    setcookie("password_changed", "password_changed", time()+5);
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

And then fetch the cookie at your login page as :

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['password_changed']) && $_COOKIE['password_changed'] == "password_changed") {
    $message = "Your Password Is Successfuly Changed.!";
}
```

And then `echo` the `$message` with using `isset()` in an `if` function inside a `Div`..!

OR

You can directly do it like this way :

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['password_changed']) && $_COOKIE['password_changed'] == "password_changed") {
    echo "<div class='class_name'><h2 align='center'>Hey,Your Password Is Changed<h2></div>";
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a simple task that much complex. if any one change the message in the url there is harm. Not understand this totally

Comment: @urfusion : Now updated the answer so if anyone manipulates the message there will be no harm..!

Comment: when you are passing just a message in url while you are not login then how it harm anything. Didn't get it !! BTW Still no one can recommended your way to do this simple task. it will make code complex and as well increase processing time.

Comment: @urfusion : It isn't harming anything at all..but it looks ugly and it's not professional way to use even `GET` for passing messages between pages..!

Comment: you know you can share any website url on fb by query string. hmm sorry its not a standard way..  You should report a bug there. https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fa%2F36793283%2F869105%3Fsfb%3D2&ref=fbshare&t=Answer%3AInserting+div+after+destroyed+session+in+login+page

Comment: @urfusion: I am just a beginner learner but even I know where to use `GET` it's stupid to use `GET` for passing static messages between pages and facebook sharing page that doesn't concerns what I am trying to tell you besides it's better to use `GET` for passing dynamic things which doesn't cause any harm..! as passing data through `GET` is easy can be done in a `URL` but using `POST` method needs a form and can be done also through `CURL`..!

Answer (score 0):

you just set a session variable .

```
<?php

$_SESSION['LOGIN_MSG']="<DIV>SUCCESS</DIV>";
$_SESSION['LOGIN_MSG']="<DIV>FAILED</DIV>";

if(isset($_SESSION['LOGIN_MSG']))
{

    echo $_SESSION['LOGIN_MSG'];

    unset($_SESSION['LOGIN_MSG']);

}  ?>
```